# Upload file with curl php by custom header

Tags: php, curl

This headers sends by my programs to a adress:

```
--55ae49448a20c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="chat_id"
Content-Length: 9

108432389
--55ae49448a20c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="Untitled.png"
Content-Length: 16252
Content-Type: image/png

 PNG
```

I want to POST 2 varibles (chat_id) and (photo) by the following code.
**Attempted Code:**

```
    <?php
$params  = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"chat_id\"\r\n"
    . "Content-Length: 9\r\n\r\n"
    . "\r\n"
    . "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"Untitled.png\"\r\n"
    . "Content-Length: ".filesize("Untitled.png")."\r\n"
    . "Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n"
    . file_get_contents("Untitled.png");
$request_headers    = array();
$request_headers[]  = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($params);
$url     = 'http://example.com';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
$reply = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Is there any other way for do that !?
My attempted code gives me 400 Bad Gatway error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's **TOTALLY** unnecessary. You're doing way too much that CURL can do far better (and properly) itself.

```
$post = array(
    'chat_id' => 108432389,
    'photo' => '@Untitled.jpg'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

old-school php curl used `@` in the value field to signify a file to be uploaded. Newer versions use [curlfile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work in telegram api:
`<?php
$post = array(
    'chat_id' => 108432389,
    'photo' => realpath('ur.png')
);
$url     = 'https://api.telegram.org/(MyToken)/SendPhoto';
$ch = curl_init($url);
$headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$reply = curl_exec($ch);
?>`